# sychronous webclient communication between springboot applications when deployed to aws ecs

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, amazon-ecs, netflix-eureka

I have deployed my springboot microservice to aws ecs.But i found that my eureka server is not avaliable after deployed to aws ecs which make my apllication cannot communicate between microservice which should be work in my local machine.The application should on different port in the same ip address

Here is the error:

```
2023-02-27T05:53:34.937Z ERROR [api-gateway,,]` 1 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_API-GATEWAY/***:api-gateway:8080 - was unable to send heartbeat!
```

Later on i have checked on aws ecs and i found that the aws ecs not supported to third party application,but there are inbound discovery service in aws ecs.Hence i have tried to to make request in webclient using dns+port directly.But it also fail with the following error:

```
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112) ~[eureka-client-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) ~[eureka-client-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) ~[eureka-client-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) ~[eureka-client-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClien
```

It seems that can i just remove the eureka-client and use aws dns + port can solve the problem or how can achieve the communication between microservice in ecs .The dns bellow is the ecs generated endpoint + 8080(port on userjob microservice)
code:

```
  public Mono<user_info> finduser(String username){
            return webClientBuilder.baseUrl("http://"+dns).build().get()
                    .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                            .path("UserJob/get/Byusername/{username}")//"http://localhost:8082/Checkuser/{id}")
                            .build(username))
                    .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(user_info.class);
    }
```

docker-compose yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.3.0
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.0
    container_name: broker
    ports:
      # To learn about configuring Kafka for access across networks see
      # https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/
      - "9092:9092"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL://broker:29092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1

#  dbmysql:
#    container_name: dbmysql
#    image: mysql:latest
#    restart: unless-stopped
#    environment:
#      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "password"
#      MYSQL_USER: "admin"
#      MYSQL_DATABASE: freelance
#      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "password"
#
#    ports:
#      - "3307:3307"
#    volumes:
#      - /var/lib/docker/volumes/freelance_volume/_data
#
#  mongodb:
#    container_name: mongodb
#    image: mongo:latest
#    restart: unless-stopped
#    ports:
#      - "27017:27017"
#    volumes:
#      - /data/db

  zipkin:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin
    container_name: zipkin
    ports:
        - "9411:9411"



  eureka-server:
    image: alex0121/eureka-server:latest
    container_name: eureka-server
    depends_on:
      - zipkin
    build:
      context: eureka-server/.
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.layered
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker


  api-gateway:
    image: alex0121/api-gateway:latest
    build:
      context: api-gateway/.
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.layered
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server
      - zipkin
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker


  notification:
    image: alex0121/notification:latest
    build:
      context: notification/.
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.layered
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server
      - broker
      - zipkin
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker


  chatroom:
    image: alex0121/chatroom:latest
    build:
      context: chatroom/.
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.layered
    ports:
      - "8084:8084"
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server
      - zipkin

    environment:
        - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker



  userjob:
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server
      - zipkin
    image: alex0121/userjob:latest
    container_name: userjob
    build:
      context: userjob/.
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.layered #docker file path (. means root directory)
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear to me from a network Point-of-View what you are trying to achieve. Is Eureka running on a different EC2?

Because it's seems like a connection issue to me. To solve connection issues inside VPCs, please check

- That the DNS names are reachable (try to ping them from inside the machines)
- That the security groups of the EC2 Instances allow the traffic (try to execute a curl on the ip/dns+port from the other machine)
- That everything is located in the same VPC or the VPCs are connected to each other
- That NACLs and RouteTables allow the Traffic (which might not be necessary if you just use one VPC).

Since you are using HTTP**S** please also check the inner exception for certificate errors.